# how to consume WCF service from SSIS?

Tags: wcf, ssis

anyone have any idea what is the proper approach to call WCF service from SSIS? It is ok if i use WCFTestClient. But if using SSIS following some online tutorials i encounter the following errors: can anyone advise?

> Error: 0x1 at Script Task:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Secure
>   channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote
>   endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by
>   the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message with Action
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including
>   security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None). at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message
>   message, EndpointAddress target) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.ThrowIfFault(Message
>   message, EndpointAddress target) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message
>   incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState) --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you using Web Service task connect / Script task to connect to web services? this link may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24999/Calling-a-Web-Service-from-a-SQL-Integration-Servi

Comment: Yes i am using script task to connect to WCF service